# Rust: "cannot infer the value of const parameter" when a default is provided

Tags: rust

I'm providing a default value for a const generic type but the Rust compiler tells me it "cannot infer the value of const parameter". It seems to ignore the default. Am I using this feature wrong? Is this how it is supposed to work? Then why use defaults at all? I use nightly 1.60.

```rust
const DEFAULT_N: usize = 73;

struct Foo<const N: usize = DEFAULT_N>;

impl<const N: usize> Foo<N> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        println!("N is: {}", N);
        Self
    }
}

fn main() {
    Foo::new();
}
```

Comment: I never used this feature, but should't you specify the default value also in the `impl` declaration ?

Comment: @Peterrabbit No, specifying a default in an `impl` block is an error. (`error: defaults for const parameters are only allowed in struct, enum, type, or trait definitions`)

Comment: @cdhowie Yep, that's what I'm seeing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it working like this

```rs
const DEFAULT_N: usize = 73;

struct Foo<const N: usize = DEFAULT_N>;

impl<const N: usize> Foo<N> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        println!("N is: {}", N);
        Self
    }
}

fn main() {
    let f:Foo = Foo::new(); // just added the asked type annotation here
}
```

Comment: Interesting, so it looks like currently defaults only apply when naming the type itself and not using a member of it. The `N` on the right is inferred from the `N` on the left, and the `N` on the left is inferred to be the default. This seems like it could be a bug and might be worth opening a github issue to see what the devs think.

Comment: Has anyone opened an issue on github in regards to this? If not, I can.

Comment: @JonathanWoollett-light Sounds like no-one did. Did you?